# iphone keyboard sound

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm looking for the default keyboard sound, when a key is pressed on the iPhone.  Does anyone know if I can download a .caf or .wav of this sound.  Or if I can access it from within a program>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Finder, navigate to

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework

The filename is `Tock.aiff`

Comment: actually, they seem to be almost identical in sound. maybe Tock is slightly louder.

Comment: I also found "iPod Click.aiff" but it sounds more like a tap than a click.

Comment: Thanks a lot, never thought of checking in there

Answer (score 0):

Found this on my iPod Touch 1st generation, it kind of sounds like the keyclick but I'm not sure:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/scrollerClick.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

For simulators with version >10.0, keyboard click sounds (and other UI sounds) can found in :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk/System/Library/Audio/UISounds
```

The format is .caf which can be converted in .wav using Quick Time export.